# Ubuntu Functionality using a USB Wifi dongle with Realtek RTL881AU

Tags: wireless, usb, internet, realtek, netgear

earlier tonight set up my desktop rig with a dual boot for Ubuntu and the installation ran fine except I have one problem. I cannot access the Internet with my USB dongle.

This USB dongle is the only way I can access the web in my current living situation.

In my research the past few hours, I discovered this this Wifi dongle is not compatible with Linux by default and some installations are required. I've tried multiple solutions all over the web to fix this and none of them have worked, and I noticed that most of them are at the most two years old.

Is there a working solution for this in 2020? It uses Realtek RTL881AU

Comment: what version are you running? Linux >5.0 has built-in drivers for Realtek WiFi.

Comment: I'm using the latest build of Ubuntu

Comment: I see. what is the output of `lsmod`?

Comment: A lot, but for the the part pertaining to realtk is 

`realtek                24576  1`

Comment: the Realtek Wifi drivers are often named `RTLxxxx` of `rxxxxx`... did you try https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au?

Comment: In all honesty I don't know. I've worked through multiple tutorials, but I will try it now. I'm kind of a Linux noob though so I'm not sure what the process would be

Comment: Please be specific on what you consider "*the latest build of Ubuntu*".  We don't support *development* or *daily* builds of Ubuntu on this site so please be specific. Main desktop/server releases of Ubuntu use a *yy.mm* format, specialist release use *yy* and *dailies* are off-topic so don't matter.  https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I apologize, I'm new around here. It's version 20.04

Comment: It seems that even though Linux >5.0 introduced support for a lot of Realtek Wifi, unfortunately your model RTL8812AU isn't one of them yet. Sorry, I hope the github repo I linked solves your issue until the driver is finally introduced into the kernel proper.